# Let $f(x)$ be a non-negative decreasing function, goes to 0, what can we say about the asymptotic behaviour of $\sum_{p \leq x} f(p)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

As we know by the PNT tha primes have density $\frac{1}{\log x}$, so I am wondering whether we always have

$$
\sum_{p \leq x} f(p) \sim \int_1^x \frac{f(t)}{\log t} dt 
$$

I have varified it for $f(x) = \frac{1}{\log x}, \frac{1}{\log \log x}$ to get Mertens Theorem etc.

Is it the case for any $f$ (having the property as mentioned in title) or depend on growth of $f$?

Comment: Some other interesting options might include $\frac 1n, \frac 1{n\log n}, e^{-n}, n^{-q},\dots$.

Comment: Have you tried [partial summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula)?

Comment: @TravorLZH I have applied but without having any information about the growth of $f(x)$, I am not able to estimate the term $\int_2^x f'(t) \pi(t) dt$.

Comment: @Sushant Of couse you will need some information on the growth rate of $f(x)$.

Comment: Gary's answer is good and thorough; I thought it would be worth pointing out that if $f(p)$ decays fast enough that the sum on the left converges, then the asymptotic will almost certainly fail since it would imply the unlikely equality of two constants (the limits of both sides).

Comment: Here is a nice general result on partial sums of positive sequences: if $a_n \sim b_n$ and either $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n$ or $\sum_{n \geq 1} b_n$ is $\infty$, then both are and $\sum_{n \leq x} a_n \sim \sum_{n \leq x} b_n$ as $x \to \infty$.  Such a result is completely false when $\sum a_n$ or $\sum b_n$ converges, e.g., the sequences $a_n = 1/(n^2+n)$ and $b_n  = 1/n^2$ don't have asymptotic partial sums since $\sum_{n \leq x} 1/(n^2+n) \to 1$ and $\sum_{n \leq x} 1/n^2 \to \pi^2/6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that $f'$ exists and is integrable. Using [Abel's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula),
$$
\sum\limits_{p \le x} {f(p)}  = \pi (x)f(x) - \int_2^x {\pi (t)f'(t){\rm d}t} .
$$
By [the prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem),
$$
\pi (t) = \operatorname{Li}(t) + R(t)
$$
where $\operatorname{Li}$ is the [offset logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Offset_logarithmic_integral) and $R(t)$ is the [error term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime-counting_function_in_terms_of_the_logarithmic_integral). Thus, by integrating once by parts,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{p \le x} {f(p)} & = \pi (x)f(x) - \int_2^x {\operatorname{Li}(t)f'(t){\rm d}t}  - \int_2^x {R(t)f'(t){\rm d}t} 
\\ & = \int_2^x {\frac{{f(t)}}{{\log t}}{\rm d}t}  + R(x)f(x) + \operatorname{Li}(2)f(2) - \int_2^x {R(t)f'(t){\rm d}t} .
\end{align*}
Consequently, if
$$
R(x)f(x) + \operatorname{Li}(2)f(2) - \int_2^x {R(t)f'(t){\rm d}t}  = o\!\left( {\int_2^x {\frac{{f(t)}}{{\log t}}{\rm d}t} } \right)
$$
as $x\to+\infty$, then
$$
\sum\limits_{p \le x} {f(p)} \sim \int_2^x {\frac{{f(t)}}{{\log t}}{\rm d}t}
$$
as $x\to+\infty$.